# Медведь "не убитый" или "неубитый"?

Tags: орфография

В общеизвестной поговорке про шкуру медведя, какой он, собственно: "не убитый" или "неубитый"? Мне попадалось раздельное написание, но насколько это правильно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неубитый медведь - тот, которого не убили. Это причастие. Зависимого слова нет, противопоставления нет - пишем слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Неубитый медведь. 
Предыдущий автор ответил верно.